# YouTube API v3 search - don't return all videos

Tags: api, search, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API v3 and here is my problem:

For example this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHKMfkiq1OA

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=My_Keys&id=MHKMfkiq1OA
```

was published at 2013-04-02T11:40:24.000Z

By when i try search for this movie using search engine like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&key=MY_KEY&publishedAfter=2013-04-02T11:40:20.000Z&publishedBefore=2013-04-02T11:40:30.000Z
```

There is no result for this search, why?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, "publishedBefore" and "publishedAfter" aren't really search parameters, but are more like filters that are applied to search results. If your API call only includes those two parameters, then there is nothing to base a search on. Notice that with this call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&q=movies&key=MY_KEY&publishedBefore=2013-04-02T11:40:24.300Z&publishedAfter=2013-04-02T11:40:20.000Z
```

The single video is returned. In essence, omitting the 'q' parameter is like telling YouTube to search for an empty string.

Comment: But in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list the q parametr is listed as optional parametr. Also empty string is existing in every string so when i don't specify they q parametr it should return EVERY video. Am i wrong?

Comment: It's optional in the sense that you won't get an error when you don't include it. But not specifying the q parameter does not mean "return all," in the same way that submitting a blank Google search doesn't mean "return all web pages." There are perfectly good reasons why you might omit the 'q' parameter ... for example, you can do a channelId or a topicId search instead. But the YouTube algorithms just don't really have a sense of date-based searching in the way you're hoping for, unfortunately.